# how they are equal: equation involving partial derivative

Tags: integration, analysis

Could anyone help me to realize why they are equal?

$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_{t_0}^{t}f(t,\tau)d\tau= \int_{t_0}^{t}(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(t,\tau))d\tau + f(t,\tau)|_{\tau=t}$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/817785/how-can-we-derive-frac-partial-partial-t-intt-t-0ft-taud-tau?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called Newton-Leibniz's Integral rule or sometimes, Leibniz Integral rule.

[See this for more information](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule?wprov=sfla1)

> $$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{\phi(t)}^{\psi(t)} f(t,s) ds = \int_{\phi(t)}^{\psi(t)} \frac{d}{dt}f(t,s) ds+f(t,\psi(t))\frac{d}{dt}\psi(t) -f(t,\phi(t))\frac{d}{dt}\phi(t).$$